# Scraping multiple html tables with the same URL but different tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm trying to **scrape** the webpage https://www.bolsadeproductos.cl/pagador/20 in order to get tha table of the bottom. But when in use the next code, i can not get all the results, only the first 10 rows. How can I loop through all the different  tags?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Edge('C:\\Users\\facun\\Documents\\msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.bolsadeproductos.cl/pagador/20')

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, attrs = {'id': 'tbl_export'})
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, just replace this line in your code:

```
driver.get('https://www.bolsadeproductos.cl/pagador/20')
```

to

```
driver.get('https://www.bolsadeproductos.cl/pagador/tablePagador/20/undefined/0')

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, attrs = {'id': 'tbl_export'})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[    Fecha Operacion Nemotecnico Vendedor Comprador            Monto   Tasa  Plazo(Dias)
0        30-06-2015     FANGLOS       LV        LV     $ 26.586.879  0,34%           30
1        26-06-2015     FANGLOS       LV        LV     $ 26.574.872  0,34%           34
2        27-05-2015     FANGLOS       LV        LV  $ 1.059.184.359  0,34%           16
3        16-06-2015     FANGLOS       LV        LV    $ 996.461.527  0,34%           37
4        16-06-2015     FANGLOS       LV        LV    $ 996.461.527  0,34%           37
..              ...         ...      ...       ...              ...    ...          ...
309      03-03-2020     FANGLOS       LV        LV      $ 8.558.358  0,26%           13
310      06-03-2020     FANGLOS       LV        LV      $ 8.560.581  0,26%           10
311      06-03-2020     AANGLOS       LV        LV     $ 63.596.531  0,26%           59
312      06-03-2020     FANGLOS       LV       BCI     $ 45.678.549  0,26%           31
313      19-05-2020     FANGLOS      BCI       BCI    $ 849.422.583  0,22%           17
```

Comment: Just for ask, how do I know the next time what is the url that i need to chane? In this case was 'https://www.bolsadeproductos.cl/pagador/20' for 'https://www.bolsadeproductos.cl/pagador/tablePagador/20/undefined/0'. My question if how do you know that this url will work?

Comment: you need a start to inspect element in google chrome (```ctrl + shift + i```),  then navigate to the Network tab and check all response. try to find the required text, then you will know which url needs to use.

Comment: Thank you very much, Roman.  This is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript, but you can use `requests` module to get the result:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.bolsadeproductos.cl/pagador/tablePagador/20/undefined/0'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
for i, row in enumerate(soup.select('tr:has(td)'), 1):
    row = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    print('{:<5}{:<15}{:<15}{:<10}{:<10}{:<20}{:<15}{:<15}'.format(i, *row))
```

Prints:

```
1    30-06-2015     FANGLOS        LV        LV        $ 26.586.879        0,34%          30             
2    26-06-2015     FANGLOS        LV        LV        $ 26.574.872        0,34%          34             
3    27-05-2015     FANGLOS        LV        LV        $ 1.059.184.359     0,34%          16             
4    16-06-2015     FANGLOS        LV        LV        $ 996.461.527       0,34%          37             
5    16-06-2015     FANGLOS        LV        LV        $ 996.461.527       0,34%          37             
6    27-05-2015     FANGLOS        LV        LV        $ 1.059.184.359     0,34%          16             

    
... all the way to:

309  23-12-2019     FANGLOS        LV        BCI       $ 193.475.303       0,26%          56             
310  03-03-2020     FANGLOS        LV        LV        $ 8.558.358         0,26%          13             
311  06-03-2020     FANGLOS        LV        LV        $ 8.560.581         0,26%          10             
312  06-03-2020     AANGLOS        LV        LV        $ 63.596.531        0,26%          59             
313  06-03-2020     FANGLOS        LV        BCI       $ 45.678.549        0,26%          31             
314  19-05-2020     FANGLOS        BCI       BCI       $ 849.422.583       0,22%          17
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this website uses a javascript loader. Look at [Selenium Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait until the page is completely loaded.